# Angular2 and Nancy: Processing error message

Tags: angular, nancy

I try to return from Nancy error message to web app based on Angular 2.

My Nancy server code:

```
    private dynamic GetSolution(dynamic arg)
    {
        string solutionName = arg.name;

        if (solutionName == "error")
        {
            var response = Json(new {message = $"error"});
            response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
            return response;
        }

        return Json(solutionService.GetSolutionByName(solutionName));
    }
```

on client side a process responses with next code:

```
onButtonClicked(name: string): void
{
    this
        .solutionsService
        .getSolutionByName(name)
        .subscribe(
            p=>this.showMessage(p.title),
            p=>this.showError(p.message));
    //this.refresh(true);
}
```

if reponse with status 200 - i receive expected object (solution with fields id and title), [image]

but if status code 0 error  (400 for example) i get unexpected object:
[image]

What i do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error was in CORS issue. In success response i added CORS headers to response, but in invalid response i didn't do it. That why Angular return to me response obhect from OPTIONS pre-flight request.